# SQL Count Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, mariadb

I am trying to use a count function to show me how many employees have the title "Sales"

```
if( !$connect)
{
die("ERROR: Cannot connect to database $db on server $server
using user name $user (".mysqli_connect_errno().
", ".mysqli_connect_error().")");
}
else
{
$userQuery = "COUNT(empID) FROM personnel WHERE jobTitle='Sales'";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $userQuery);

if (!$result)
{
    die("Could not successfully run query ($userQuery) from $db: " . 
mysqli_error($connect) );
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    print("No records found with query $userQuery");
}
else
{
     print("<h1>SALES STAFF REPORT</h1>");
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        print("<p>There are 
        ".$row['COUNT(empID)']."</p>");
    }

}
 mysqli_close($connect);   // close the connection
}
?>
```

I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(empID) FROM personnel WHERE jobTitle='Sales'' at line 1

on this line:

```
$userQuery = "COUNT(empID) FROM personnel WHERE jobTitle='Sales'";
```

I am unsure of what I am doing incorrectly, but any help would be appreciated.

End result should read "There are 4 sales staff".

My professor did include this in the assignment, not sure if that will help.

```
"There are two different MySQL functions that you can use here: you can 
modify the SELECT statement to use a MySQL aggregation function,
or you can use the MySQL function that returns the number of records in the 
result set. "
```

Comment: You are missing the `SELECT` statement, it should be `SELECT COUNT(empID) FROM personnel WHERE jobTitle='Sales'`.

Comment: I don't see a SELECT in your SELECT statement

Comment: you should $userQuery = "SELECT COUNT(empID) FROM personnel WHERE jobTitle='Sales'";

Comment: And use PDO, prepared statements

Comment: Thank you for the help! On the guide my professor provided going over the aggregate operations, she did not include select in front of it so I did not think it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `SELECT` keyword when making the statement.

**You have:**
`$userQuery = "COUNT(empID) FROM personnel WHERE jobTitle='Sales'";`

**It should be:**
`$userQuery = "SELECT COUNT(empID) FROM personnel WHERE jobTitle='Sales'";`